# Functorial way of showing that the Segre (or Plucker) morphism is a closed embedding?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}$ be quasi-coherent sheaves on a base scheme $S$. Then the $S$-schemes $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{F}), \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{G})$ are defined by a universal property: to map from an $S$-scheme $T$ (with structure map $g: T \to S$)  into $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{F})$ is the same thing as giving a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ on $T$ and a surjection $g^*(\mathcal{F}) \to \mathcal{L}$. The Segre embedding $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{F}) \times_S \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{G}) \to \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{G})$ is defined in a canonical manner using this universal property. Similarly, the Plucker embedding of the Grassmannian into a projective scheme is done by giving a morphism of the functors they represent.

The Segre and Plucker embeddings are closed immersions, as is checked locally using the definitions. However, the properness of projective space $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{Z}}$ can be easily proved using only the valuative criterion, which seems easier and more elegant (though it can also be done directly). Is there a functorial way to see that the Segre and Plucker embeddings are closed immersions?

Comment: The advantage of the local method is that it proves more: there is an open covering $(U_i)$ of the Grassmannian and open subsets $(V_i)$ of the projective space such that the Plücker map sends $U_i$to $V_i$ and the induced morphism has a retraction.


Comment: One approach to the question (in the Plücker case, say) could be to apply EGA 4 (18.12.6) (or (8.11.5), under finiteness assumptions): every proper monomorphism $X\to Y$ is a closed immersion. In fact it suffices to prove properness plus the fact that for $y\in Y$ the fiber $X_y$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Spec}\kappa(y)$. 

Properness can be deduced from the valuative criterion (if $\mathcal{F}$ is finitely generated you just prove properness of the Grassmannian). The other property is over a field.



Comment: @Akhil: I hope it's OK for you that I changed the P's into the "projective" P's. For your question, you may write down an ideal $I \subseteq \mathbb{P}(F \otimes G)$ explicitely and verify that $\mathbb{P}(F) \times_S \mathbb{P}(G)$ satisfies the same universal property as $V(I)$. I have not tried it, but this should work.

Comment: By the way, as with your other questions: Very interesting, 1+.

Comment: @Laurent Moret-Bailly: Thanks! (I would be happy to accept that as an answer.) Is there a direct way to check that $X_y$ (for $X$ the Grassmannian, $Y$ the projective space, $X \to Y$ the Plucker map) is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Spec} \kappa(y)$? 


Comment: @Martin: Yes, your edit improves the question; thanks.

Comment: @Akhil: Unfortunately, even for this special case, every proof I can think of uses some explicit computation. We are essentially trying to recover, say, a $d$-dimensional subspace $F$ of $k^n$ from its determinant line in $\Lambda^d(k^n)$, and I don't see how we can do this just by waving hands.

Comment: I just want to mention that now I have a functorial proof that the Plücker embedding is a closed immersion, using the same technique as below, namely constructing the quasi-coherent ideal and showing that the functor of points are isomorphic.

Comment: Maybe I will write another answer to this question later.There is a purely functorial way to prove Serge embedding is closed immersion based on the point of view of presheaf which was developed by Kontsevich-Rosenberg in noncommutative setting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a very interesting question. It gives another proof of the Segre embedding, makes it somehow more natural and puts it into a more general context, which I explain below.

I will just talk about the Segre embedding $\mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m \to \mathbb{P}^{n+m+nm}$. The general case of $\mathbb{P}(F) \times \mathbb{P}(G) \to \mathbb{P}(F \otimes G)$ is similar.

Let $x_0,...,x_n$ be the homogeneous coordinates of $\mathbb{P}^n$, $y_0,...,y_m$ the ones of $\mathbb{P}^m$ and $z_{00},...,z_{nm}$ the ones of $\mathbb{P}^{n+m+nm}$. The idea of the Segre embedding is $z_{ab} = x_a y_b$. Observe that with this equation we can interchange $a,c$ and $b,d$ in $z_{ab} z_{cd}$ without changing the result. Thus, consider the homogeneous ideal generated by the $z_{ab} z_{cd} - z_{cb} z_{ad}, z_{ab} z_{cd} - z_{ad} z_{cb}$ and let $I$ denote the corresponding ideal of the structure sheaf of $\mathbb{P}^{n+m+nm}$. Now I claim that $V(I)$ and $\mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m$ satisfy the same universal property. So these schemes are isomorphic, and we get a closed immersion $\mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m \to \mathbb{P}^{n+m+nm}$.

Let $X$ be a test scheme. Then $\hom(X,\mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m)$ is the set of tuples $(\mathcal{L}_1,\rho,\mathcal{L}_2,\tau)$, where $\mathcal{L}_1$ (resp. $\mathcal{L}_2$) is a line bundle on $X$ and $\rho_0,...,\rho_n$ (resp. $\tau_0,...,\tau_m$) are global generators of $\mathcal{L}_1$ (resp. $\mathcal{L}_2$).

On the other hand, $\hom(X,V(I))$ is the set of all tuples $(\mathcal{L},\sigma)$, where $\mathcal{L}$ is a line bundles on $X$ and $\sigma_{00},...,\sigma_{nm}$ are global generators of $\mathcal{L}$, which satisfy the relations $\sigma_{ab} \sigma_{cd} = \sigma_{cb} \sigma_{ad}$ and $\sigma_{ab} \sigma_{cd} = \sigma_{ad} \sigma_{cb}$.

With these descriptions, there is a very natural map $\hom(X,\mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m) \to \hom(X,V(I))$ given by $\mathcal{L} = \mathcal{L}_1 \otimes \mathcal{L}_2$ and $\sigma_{ab} = \rho_a \otimes \tau_b$. Actually this map makes sense in every abelian tensor category, but its bijectivity seems to be a special property of the abelian tensor category of quasi-coherent sheaves on a scheme (more generally, sheaves of modules on a ringed space). The usual proof uses the local explicit description of the classifying projective schemes, but you can do it directly by writing down an inverse map:

Let $\mathcal{L},\sigma$ be given as above. Construct a line bundle $\mathcal{L}_1$ as follows: For every $i$, put $X_{\rho_i} = \cup_j X_{\sigma_{ij}}$. On this open set, let $\mathcal{L}_1$ be generated freely by a symbol $\rho_i$. The cocycles $\rho_a / \rho_i$ are defined as $\sigma_{aj} / \sigma_{ij}$ for some $j$; the choice of this $j$ does not matter because of the relations for $\sigma$. Similarily we may define $\mathcal{L}_2$ with global generators $\tau_j$. It's easy to show that $\mathcal{L} \cong \mathcal{L}_1 \otimes \mathcal{L}_2$ with $\rho_i \otimes \tau_j$ corresponding to $\sigma_{ij}$.

Comment: So this is how Grothendieck *defines* the Segre embedding in EGA II (or the new edition of EGA I). There is of course an explicit description of it as well. (I realize this is tangential: I need to think about this a little!)

Comment: OK, I've thought this over: this is a very nice explanation for the Segre embedding, and one which really motivates it better. Thanks! 